# join list elements between two elements in a list

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

I have a list and I have the two list elements `start:`and `end:`. Between these two there is an undefined number of elements that I would like to join to the `start` element.
Also, `end:` can have different names but it always starts with `end:`. This is my list

```
sth_list = ['name: michael', 'age:56', 'start:','','something','is','happening','end:', 'anything could be here:', 'some other things:', 'more things:']
```

and I would like to get this

```
 ['name: michael', 'age:56', 'start: something is happening', 'end:', 'anything could be here:', 'some other things:', 'more things:']
```

what I have so far is this. But it only gives me the joined elements between start and end but I would like to have the full list as above.

```
 ''.join([element for n, element in enumerate(sth_list) if ((n>sth_list.index("start:")) & (n<sth_list.index([e for e in sth_list if e.startswith('end')][0])))])
```

Comment: General recommendation: Don't write code like this, the list comprehension contains too much logic. Code needs to be understandable, and this code is a pain to read and debug. Just write it out on multiple lines :)

Comment: This seems like a strange data structure, where does it come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the indexes of `start:` and `end:`. Then you can join them and use slice assignment to replace that part of the list with the result.

```
start = sth_list.index('start:')
end = min(i for i, s in enumerate(sth_list) if s.startswith('end:'))
sth_list[start:end] = [' '.join(sth_list[start:end])]
```

Note that this only works if there's just one `start:/end:` pair in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classical loop:

```
import re

out = []
flag = False
for item in sth_list:
    if item.startswith('end:'):
        flag = False
    if flag:
        if item:
            out[-1] += ' '+item
    else:
        out.append(item)
    if item == 'start:':
        flag = True
```

output:

```
['name: michael',
 'age:56',
 'start: something is happening',
 'end:',
 'anything could be here:',
 'some other things:',
 'more things:']
```

Comment: This doesn't look specifically for `start:` and `end:`, it just assumes that anything without `:` should be concatenated to the previous element.

Comment: @Barmar that's how I understood the question. I assumed these were dummy text, not specific delimiters

Comment: His code looks for them specifically. The question says "`end:` can have different names but it always starts with `end:`."

Comment: @Barmar easy enough to update with the same logic ;)